How to Insert Text with Background Images and a Gallery in GitHub README with a Three-Column Layout?
I'm working on my GitHub README and I want to insert an image gallery alongside text with a background image. My goal is to achieve a three-column layout that includes text with a background image and the image gallery.
While I can achieve this effect in the local Markdown preview, the layout does not display as expected once uploaded to GitHub, and the three-column layout breaks.



Local expected preview
Github unexpected preview




https://github.com/farleyrunkel/OpenGL-Lessons/blob/main/problem.gif
https://github.com/farleyrunkel/OpenGL-Lessons/blob/main/issue.png



Most importanly, I want to display a text with a background image:
<a style="font-size: 6vw; 
background-image: url('https://github.com/farleyrunkel/OpenGL-Lessons/raw/main/images/background.png');
background-size: cover; 
margin: 0;">Create Window</a>

Here is my total Markdown code:
# OpenGl Lessons

<div style="display: grid;grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); gap: 10px;">
<a style="font-size: 6vw; background-image: url('https://github.com/farleyrunkel/OpenGL-Lessons/raw/main/images/background.png');background-size: cover; margin: 0; ">Create Window</a>
    <img src="https://github.com/farleyrunkel/OpenGL-Lessons/raw/main/images/HelloWindow.gif" alt="">
    <img src="https://github.com/farleyrunkel/OpenGL-Lessons/raw/main/images/HelloWindow2.gif" alt="">
    <img src="https://github.com/farleyrunkel/OpenGL-Lessons/raw/main/images/HelloTriangle.gif" alt="">
...
</div>

